# Printing ten values from each array alternating between them until both are empty

Tags: linux, awk

Suppose I have the following script and it is iterating over two arrays and prints the the values alternating between them. I feed the Script the following file:

```
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
```

Awk Script:

```awk
BEGIN{ FS = "\t" }
{ a[o++]=$1; b[c++]=$2 }
END{ while (++co <= 5 ) { 
        for ( k = 1+count; k <= 2+count; k++ ){ if (length(a) >= 0){ print a[k]; delete a[k]} }
        for ( ki = 1+count; ki <= 2+count; ki++ ){ if (length(b) >= 0){ print b[ki]; delete b[ki] } }
        count = k
    }
}
```

And I expect the output to be

```
1
1
2
2
1
1
2
2
1
1
2
2
```

But what I get is:

```
1
1
2
2
1
1
2
2

(followed by blank lines but they are not my issue)
```

So how to make it run until both arrays are empty and everything is printed. And how to make it work even if the arrays are of different size e.g. one caontains for example 20 more values than the other. So then just these values should be printed until the array is empty.

Comment: If you adhere to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) principle, you will receive better answers.  My guess is that your code is failing because you delete elements 1-10 and then continue referring to them

Comment: Soory that this is not fully complete but it is part of a real big script. But your suggestion makes sense to me and I see the error now. Let me try something and then I either rewrite the question or I close it. Thank you.

Comment: Hope its better now :)

Comment: awk arrays are one-indexed. Where you collect data into `a` and `b`, you write the first data to `a[0]` and `b[0]` which are never printed

Comment: @Thor Very good point. I overlooked that. Thank you :)

Comment: [edit] your question to show sample input/output for the `And how to make it work...` case at the end of your question too as your requirements are ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you all. The Input I got from Thor and Ed Morton helped me to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrt `how to make it run until both arrays are empty` - There's no need to delete the array contents.

wrt `just these values should be printed until the array is empty` - "**the** array is empty" could mean print just the values at the indices present in both arrays ("**the first** array is empty") or it could mean print all the values from both arrays ("**both arrays** are empty"). The script below assumes the latter but is easily tweaked to do the former (change `||` to `&&`).

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ a[++maxA]=$1; b[++maxB]=$2 }
END {
    while ( (prevEnd<maxA) || (prevEnd<maxB) ) {
        prt(a)
        prevEnd = prt(b)
    }
}

function prt(arr,       idx) {
    for (idx=prevEnd+1; idx<=prevEnd+2; idx++) {
        if (idx in arr) {
            print arr[idx]
        }
    }
    return (idx-1)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1
1
2
2
1
1
2
2
1
1
2
2
```